# Why is my kick command not working? (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

I've tried using a command handler and the other commands work fine. It's just the kick command that doesn't, can anyone help? https://sourceb.in/8d4f78e43a is the code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the code is pretty small, you should post it on SO instead of an external link, for archiving for the future and some other reasons you can look up

Also you should mention if you get any error logs, in this case I don't think you would have

The issue is `let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args);`

You are passing in an the array args, not a string (which `<Collection>.get()` requires, you probably meant `args[1]`:

`let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]);`